# What is the conditional code to affect IE8 browser?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I don't mean conditional comments embedded into the html. I am refering to the conditional code that can be put directly into the css file. Like:

```
*+html .myClass {} is for IE7
* html .myClass {} is for IE 6
```

what is the one for IE 8?

Comment: I don't think CSS hacks are necessary for a browser like IE8...

Comment: Agreed with Bolt.  You can utilize conditional comments differently than what you are probably used to though... http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Comment: In fact, i built a lot of websites without using _any_ browser-specific CSS (yes, including IE 6). The only thing that you _might_ need is the alpha filter hack as `opacity` fix.

Answer (score 3):

What are you trying to achieve? You shouldn't have to hack up your CSS for IE8. I don't think there is a conditional code for IE8 so if you absolutely need to have a style sheet for IE8, you might have to turn to conditional comment.

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <link href="ie8css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 3):

Conditional comment for the HTML tag, which will allow you to target .ie8 in your CSS:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class=""> <!--<![endif]-->
```

That is what's currently being used in [html5boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/).

Also, be weary of the last few paragraphs in [Paul's blog post](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/). I agree that you should try to make it work without targeting specific browsers, it at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this site](http://dimox.net/personal-css-hacks-for-ie6-ie7-ie8/), you can do the following:

```
.selector {
    property: value\0/;
}
```

> There are several similar variants of this hack, but this is the easiest. It’s very easy to remember. Just add the \0/ at the end of a CSS rule.